# Understanding compare_exchange_weak

Tags: c++, multithreading, stdatomic

The code below is the example for compare_exchange_weak from https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange_weak/

I don't understand what kinds of operations are acceptable inside the compare_exchange_weak while loop.

In the example, they are setting the newNode->next value to the oldHead pointer as long as the compare_exchange returns false.  I don't understand how this is always valid.

What happens if another thread is in the same loop, and it succeeds to change the oldHead pointer between the time we set it, and the time the compare_exchange succeeds on our thread?  Then we would have the wrong head pointer in our newNode.  I can't see why this is not possible.

For example, if I put a sleep(5), or do some long calculation in the loop after I set the ->next value, would this work?

The loop marked "WHAT IS SAFE TO DO HERE" is the part I don't get.

```
// atomic::compare_exchange_weak example:
#include <iostream>       // std::cout
#include <atomic>         // std::atomic
#include <thread>         // std::thread
#include <vector>         // std::vector

// a simple global linked list:
struct Node { int value; Node* next; };
std::atomic<Node*> list_head (nullptr);

void append (int val) {     // append an element to the list
  Node* oldHead = list_head;
  Node* newNode = new Node {val,oldHead};

  // what follows is equivalent to: list_head = newNode, but in a thread-safe way:
  while (!list_head.compare_exchange_weak(oldHead,newNode))

    newNode->next = oldHead;                 // <-- WHAT IS SAFE TO DO HERE?

    // WHAT IF I DO SOMETHING STUPID LIKE THIS?
    //sleep(5);

    // OR LIKE THIS:
    //some_long_calculation();    

  }

int main ()
{
  // spawn 10 threads to fill the linked list:
  std::vector<std::thread> threads;
  for (int i=0; i<10; ++i) threads.push_back(std::thread(append,i));
  for (auto& th : threads) th.join();

  // print contents:
  for (Node* it = list_head; it!=nullptr; it=it->next)
    std::cout << ' ' << it->value;
  std::cout << '\n';

  // cleanup:
  Node* it; while (it=list_head) {list_head=it->next; delete it;}

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Then the compare_exchange fails and you try again with the new oldHead.

Comment: But the compare and exchange is on newNode, not newNode->next.  I don't see how we can modify a member of newNode, then assume that oldHead didn't possibly change before we get to the compare_exchange

Comment: The compare-exchange is "if list_head == oldHead then list_head = newNode else oldHead = list_head".

Comment: @RaymondChen - That is the clarification I needed.  I was completely reasoning about that the wrong way.  It makes complete sense what that pseudo-code representation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically you can do whatever you like inside the loop. `compare_exchange` (both, weak and strong) only ever succeed *if and only if* the value of the variable to be updated equals the first provided argument. In your example, `list_head.compare_exchange_weak(oldHead,newNode)` can only ever succeed iff `list_head == oldHead`. So if inside the loop you have a sleep or some long calculation, then there is a good chance that some other thread is faster and updates `list_head`, so your `compare_exchange` operation is likely to fail. It is important to note that the first parameter is passed by reference. If the compare fails, the given parameter is updated with the new value.

Storing `oldHead` in `newNode->next` is perfectly safe, because if subsequent the `compare_exchange` fails, `oldHead` is updated, the new value is again stored in `newNode->next` and we try again (and again, and again, ...) until the `compare_exchange` eventually succeeds. When that is the case, it is guaranteed that the value stored in `newNode->next` matches the one we just replaced in `list_head` - voilà, we have successfully inserted the node in the list.

```cpp
  // what follows is equivalent to:
  //   newNode->next = list_head;
  //   list_head = newNode;
  // but in a thread-safe way:
  while (!list_head.compare_exchange_weak(oldHead,newNode)) {
    // if we are here, the compare_exchange_weak has failed, but
    // oldHead has been updated with the current value from list_head
    newNode->next = oldHead;
  }
  // if we are here, the compare_exchange_weak was successful, i.e., the value
  // in list_head (oldHead) did not change between our assignment to newNode->next
  // and the subsequent (successful) compare_exchange.
```

---

The difference the weak and strong version is that `compare_exchange_weak` may fail spuriously. That is, it may even fail in cases where the comparison yields true. The reason why there why there is weak version is that on architectures that implement compare-exchange using LL/SC, a `compare_exchange_weak` is cheaper than the strong version. In general, if you have a retry loop like in your example, you should prefer `compare_exchange_weak`, because if you really have a (rare) spurious failure, we simply perform another retry.

Comment: This answer would be improved by some comments about what does differentiate the weak and strong alternatives.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thanks for the hint! I originally planned to included that, but ultimately forgot. I've added it now.

Comment: @mpoeter, I marked this as the answer, but it would be good if you could include the pseudocode that RaymondChen commented above - something like "if list_head == oldHead then list_head = newNode else oldHead = list_head".  That is the real point that I was missing in my studying the example.

Comment: @ttemple I included the code with some comments - is that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

`compare_exchange_(weak/strong)` are designed for general modification of the data for atomics. Not entirely sure what are the differences between the two - I think it something about the case when the atomic is not lock free and failing to obtain the lock for several times.

How one performs a general modification when one cannot lock the data? Think of it. You compute some general function of the atomic data but the data was modified in the meanwhile. It is impossible to avoid because one cannot lock the atomics.

So what people came up is to check whether the data was changed from the time the function was initiated and if it wasn't then replace it with new value. Otherwise it just replaces the expected with current value. So usually one simply retries to compute the function until the data is unchanged between the computations or the computation becomes unnecessary.

Example: you have an integer `x` and you want to update atomic integer `y` with `max(x,y)` while another thread might be doing the same with a different value of `x`.

So theoretically you can put any function in for `compare_exchange_(weak/strong)` but it will not be practical if the computation time is very long as then price of retry is too big. Use mutexes in such cases so no retries are needed.

Comment: The `weak` version is allowed to spuriously fail, e.g. because of an ABA modification by another thread, or even just another thread storing to something else in the same cache line (or a nearby cache line in the same "monitor" region).  This means the CAS itself can be implemented without a retry loop on [LL/SC machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load-link/store-conditional) (most non-x86).  Using CAS-strong in a normal retry loop like this would usually compile to a double-nested loop for most RISCs, unless a compiler was aggressive at applying the as-if rule to atomics.